# Bold subsection numbers with hyperref

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, amsart

When I use the amsart document class and leave a subsection title empty, then the subsection number is bold. Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\subsection{} Text
\end{document}
```

Strangely, when I include the hyperref package, subsection numbers do not get bolded any more. MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\subsection{} Text
\end{document}
```

Is there a way I can make subsection numbers appear in bold when using hyperref? I am afraid to break some of the functionality of hyperref if I redefine the \subsection command after loading hyperref.

Comment: the fact that you get bold numbers with `{}` is entirely accidental and fragile series of unplanned expansions.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Actually it seems to be a wanted behavior: line 1056 of `amsart.cls` has `\ifnum #2=\tw@ \def\@secnumfont{\bfseries}\fi` to be executed when `#8` (the title) is empty.

Comment: I assumed it was wanted because subsection numbers don't really stand out if there is no (bold) title next to them.

Comment: Using an inline heading with no actual heading seems to be mis-use of the heading really. Apart from the wrong font you get double space, the space intended before the heading and the space intended after the heading.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- the bolding is intentional, for the reason given: because if there's no heading, the numbers don't stand out.  (pretty sure there's a comment on this in `amsclass.dtx`.  but `hyperref` wasn't a consideration when the change was made; will check into that.)  authors use (sub)sectioning with no header text, so it has to be catered for, undesirable though it may be to editors.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- i think this hasn't actually been encountered in articles, only in books, where the style is different anyhow.  i'll have to check.  but it *is* a bug and will be addressed as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `amsart` class indeed has the feature that if the argument to `\subsection` is empty, then the number is printed boldface, while normally it is medium series.

I don't like this feature at all, personally. However, what happens is that the code in `\@sect` that does the job is (line numbers refer to `amsart.cls`)

```
1055     \@ifempty{#8}{%
1056       \ifnum #2=\tw@ \def\@secnumfont{\bfseries}\fi}{}%
```

but when `hyperref` is loaded, the argument `#8` is

```
\Sectionformat{<title>}{2}
```

so it is not empty as far as `\@ifempty` is concerned.

Here's a patch for it.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
% we need to patch the saved version of \@sect
\providecommand{\H@old@sect}{} % so this doesn't choke if hyperref is removed
\xpatchcmd{\H@old@sect}
  {\@ifnotempty{#8}}
  {\checkempty@title{#8}{}}
  {}{}
\xpatchcmd{\H@old@sect}
  {\@ifempty{#8}}
  {\checkempty@title{#8}}
  {}{}
\xpatchcmd{\H@old@sect}
  {\@ifempty{#8}}
  {\checkempty@title{#8}}
  {}{}
\def\checkempty@title#1{\checkempty@title@aux#1}
\def\checkempty@title@aux#1#2#3{\@ifempty{#2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\subsection{} Text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Actually, there *is* a bug in `amsart`: if you have one subsection with empty title, all subsequent section numbers are typeset boldface.

In order to cure this bug another couple of patches are needed:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
% we need to patch the saved version of \@sect
\providecommand{\H@old@sect}{} % so this doesn't choke if hyperref is removed
\xpatchcmd{\H@old@sect}
  {\@ifnotempty{#8}}
  {\checkempty@title{#8}{}}
  {}{}
\xpatchcmd{\H@old@sect}
  {\@ifempty{#8}}
  {\checkempty@title{#8}}
  {}{}
\xpatchcmd{\H@old@sect}
  {\@ifempty{#8}}
  {\checkempty@title{#8}}
  {}{}
\xpatchcmd{\H@old@sect}
  {\def\@secnumfont}
  {\gdef\@secnumfont}
  {}{}
\def\checkempty@title#1{\checkempty@title@aux#1}
\def\checkempty@title@aux#1#2#3{\@ifempty{#2}}
% patch the bug of amsart
\xapptocmd{\@seccntformat}
  {\noexpand\reset@secnumfont}
  {}{}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \edef\reset@secnumfont{%
    \gdef\noexpand\@secnumfont{\expandafter\noexpand\@secnumfont}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Test}
\subsection{} Text

\section{Test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the section numbers are bold:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\def\@secnumfont{\bfseries}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
\section{Test}

\subsection{} Text
\end{document}
```

If you specify an empty heading then the font that is specified for the heading text is unfortunately applied to the number, however you should not rely on that mis-feature as it could be fixed.

---

an enpty heading does not just make the one heading have bold numbers it affects all headings at all levels from the point on, consider

```
\documentclass{amsart}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}

\subsection{x} Text

\subsection{} Text

\subsection{} Text


\subsection{x} Text

\section{test2}

\end{document}
```

which makes

[image]

---

this fixes the bug with an empty heading changing the font of all following headings, and gets the right fonts in hyperref, it still has extra horizontal space in the hyperref case

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
%\def\@secnumfont{\bfseries}

\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
  \edef\@toclevel{\ifnum#2=\@m 0\else\number#2\fi}%
  \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \let\@secnumber\@empty
  \else \@xp\let\@xp\@secnumber\csname the#1\endcsname\fi
  \@tempskipa #5\relax
  \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth
    \let\@svsec\@empty
  \else
    \refstepcounter{#1}%
    \edef\@secnumpunct{%
      \ifdim\@tempskipa>\z@ % not a run-in section heading
        \@ifnotempty{#8}{.\@nx\enspace}%
      \else
        \@ifempty{#8}{.}{.\@nx\enspace}%
      \fi
    }%
%%%%
    \def\zz{#8}%
    \def\tmp{\Sectionformat{}{2}}%
    \ifx\zz\tmp\def\zz{}\fi
    \let\zzz\@secnumfont
%%%%
    \expandafter\@ifempty\expandafter{\zz}{%
      \ifnum #2=\tw@ \def\@secnumfont{\bfseries}\fi}{}%
    \protected@edef\@svsec{%
      \ifnum#2<\@m
        \@ifundefined{#1name}{}{%
          \ignorespaces\csname #1name\endcsname\space
        }%
      \fi
      \@seccntformat{#1}%
    }%
     \let\@secnumfont\zzz
  \fi
  \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@ % then this is not a run-in section heading
    \begingroup #6\relax
    \@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}{\interlinepenalty\@M #8\par}%
    \endgroup
    \ifnum#2>\@m \else \@tocwrite{#1}{#8}\fi
  \else
  \def\@svsechd{#6\hskip #3\@svsec
    \expandafter\@ifnotempty\expandafter{\zz}{\ignorespaces#8\unskip
       \@addpunct.}%
    \ifnum#2>\@m \else \@tocwrite{#1}{#8}\fi
  }%
  \fi
  \global\@nobreaktrue
  \@xsect{#5}%
}

\def\@seccntformat#1{%
  \protect\textup{\@secnumfont
    \csname the#1\endcsname
    \protect\@secnumpunct
  }%
}

\makeatletter


\begin{document}
\section{Test}

\subsection{x} Text

\subsection{} Text

\subsection{} Text


\subsection{x} Text

\section{test2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Doesn't this solution also make section numbers bold? How would you arrange for only the subsection numbers (and possibly subsubsection numbers) to be bold?

Comment: @Johnny it is a feature of the ams design that the same number font is used at all levels, you could change it of course but, there are limits to which it makes sense to change the style of a publisher class rather than use a generic class that is designed to be customised.

Comment: I see your point; on the other hand, making section numbers bold looks somewhat strange because the section titles themselves are not bold. Ultimately, I just want the style intended by the publisher, which gets somehow broken by hyperref.

Comment: @Johnny but since egreg points out it's a feature I suppose I should show how to make the feature work with hyperref, i'll updat eanswer in a bit

Comment: @Johnny but note your empty heading also makes all headings at all levels bold! see my update... (fix will need to be more extensive than I thought....)

Comment: @Johnny see update, I may come back later and look at horizontal space